# Как перекрасить адресную строку браузера

Tags: html, мобильная-разработка

[image: Воть]

Господа, подскажите, как можно перекрасить адресную строку браузера? Сколько не рылся в коде, ничего подходящего не нашел.

Comment: Мне кажется это загружена тема для браузера

Comment: нет, на разных сайтах свой background - именно в свою цветовую тему, так что ваш вариант исключен

Comment: Напишите, какие именно браузеры вас интересуют?

Comment: @Mikl, на картинке не видно, что это android Google Chrome ?

Comment: Да хотя бы Google Chrome, мне сама методика нужна

Answer (score 7, accepted):

здесь есть описание для разработчиков: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android

пример кода:

```
<!-- Chrome, Firefox OS and Opera -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4">
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#4285f4">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="#4285f4">
```

Answer (score 4):

Используйте метатег:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#db5945">
```