# Как изменить цвет вкладки в Яндекс.Браузере?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, toolbar, яндекс-браузер

Как изменить цвет вкладки в Яндекс.Браузере с того, который формируется по иконке сайта на произвольный?

На официальном сайте Яндекса есть только информация о виджетах, выводимых в закладках: https://tech.yandex.ru/browser/tableau/doc/dg/concepts/create-widget-docpage/

Он влияет на изменение цвета вкладки, но крайне нестабильно. После очистки кэша и перезагрузки страницы вкладка становится нужного цвета, но при открытии новых, ранее не открытых страниц в браузере заголовок по-прежнему формируется по иконке.

Сам код манифеста виджета:

```
{
    "api_version": 4,
    "layout":
    {
        "logo": "/favicon.png",
        "color": "#fff"
    }
}
```

Еще нашел такой код:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="ya-title=#3B8DBD,ya-dock=#3B8DBD">
```

Но толку от него нет, он ничего не меняет.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618270/178988?

Comment: @Qwertiy в том все и дело, в сети есть рабочий код для chrome, ios, windows phone, но нет для браузера яндекса.

Comment: Хромовский способ не работает?

Comment: @vp_arth неа, работает только тот, который написал выше, когда его подключаешь через манифест <link rel="yandex-tableau-widget" href="/manifest.json?7" /> но он нестабильно работает

Comment: если кратко, суть в том, чтобы убрать цвет вкладки, формирующейся по иконке на белый (сама иконка черная, соответственно браузер ее перевод в белую, а саму вкладку делает черной). самое смешное, что вкладка с сайтом яндекса никак не окрашивается, хотя по их логике там должен быть красный (под цвет логотипа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Официальный ответ от службы техподдержки Яндекса:

> Цвет активной вкладки определяется автоматически его виджетом. Если у
>   сайта есть свой логотип для виджета на странице Табло, то оформление
>   вкладки будет ему соответствовать.
>
> Как сделать виджет, Вы можете прочитать здесь:
>   https://tech.yandex.ru/browser/tableau/doc/dg/concepts/create-widget-docpage/
>
> Если виджета у сайта нет, в этом случае цвет вкладки будет взят из
>   фавиконки сайта.

P.S. От себя добавлю, что в ходе экспериментов выяснилось, что цвет фона в большинстве случаев берется из первого заполненного верхнего правого пикселя иконки и делается на несколько тонов темнее. В ряде случаев цвет формируется по другим алгоритмам (в частности, для очень светлых или очень темных иконок, а также для изображений с сочетанием разных цветов).

К сожалению, на практике Яндекс.Браузер работает с виджетом не совсем корректно, новые открываемые страницы красятся по цвету иконки сайта, а при манипуляциях с history браузера (ajax и т.д.) цвет берется из параметра "color" (цвет логотипа виджета не влияет на окрашивание). Будем надеяться, что в новых версиях браузера все будет работать правильно.